# Using original origin's call filter for proxy pallet's proxy

Tags: proxy, origin, batch, pallet-proxy

In the proxy pallet's `do_proxy` function, a newly authenticated origin is constructed from the `real` account. This is explicitly done.
Is there a particular reason for this?

Can I just use the same origin and then use set_caller_from to set it to `real`?
I would like to do this to ensure that the restrictions (one particular call filter) I apply to the origin in `utility.batch` are sustained even if `utility.batch` wraps proxy calls to attempt to avoid the restrictions.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.
Please let me know if more info is required